# Get the first element's property from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

I got an array from the response to a HTTP request using `const alerts = response.data;` and passed it to `function createData(alerts)`. In this function I tried to get the property `createdAt` from the first element of this array using: `var temp = alerts[0].createdAt`. Note that this array is not empty. This is the result of `var temp = alerts[0]; console.log(temp);`: [This is alerts[0]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdm9u.png)

The error I got from *console.log(temp)*:

> *TypeError: Cannot read property 'createdAt' of undefined*
>   How do I get the first element's `createdAt` value?

Comment: most likely your array is empty when you do `arr[0].createdAt`, which might be because your array is being populated asynchronously, but hard to tell from what you've provided. If possible, please try and create a [mre]

Comment: Can you add more of a code sample please?  Show us _how_ your setting the array object and _how_ you're trying to get the data.

Comment: Added more information

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the right way, if `createdAt` is undefined that mean you doesn't read the right object

```js
const array =  [{id: 1, seen:true, createdAt: "01-01-01"}]
console.log(array[0].createdAt) // 01-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually It should work. there might be something wrong in how you are accessing the variable.

```js
let a = [{id: 1, seen:true, createdAt: "01-01-01"}, {id: 2, seen:true, createdAt: "01-01-01"}]
var temp = a[0].createdAt;
console.log(temp)
```